# Title of book set in space with trepanning

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for the title of a book I read in the 90s about an organism on a space ship that may have come from the deep sea and it kills everyone on board until someone realizes they can trepan the skull and release the pressure.

It may include an estranged husband/wife team; one in space and one on earth.

Comment: What comes from the deep sea, the organism? Does it come from a deep sea on earth, or is it from another planet? If everyone on board is killed, who realize that they can trepan the organism's skull? The organism has a skull, so I guess it's a vertebrate? How does it kill? With a weapon such as a sword or raygun, or does it strangle people with its arms or tentacles, or does it poison them? How do they manage to capture and subdue the organism so that they can trepan its skull?

Comment: No I think the user means that it's a microorganism which seems to make some sort of pressure build up in the people's skulls, at which point you can perform the trepanning procedure to release said pressure.

Comment: @Mooz I thought the creature from the deeps had some high pressure fluid trapped in its skull and, maddened with pain, was killing everyone it met. But now I think you are probably right. How did you do that? Do you have the power to read minds?